# How do I define an action without having to implement a reducer for it?

Tags: redux-toolkit

I'm converting some existing redux code to the toolkit way.  We have a lot of actions that trigger thunks (to load data from backend) but dont have a reducer.  Our pattern being the load/success/fail triple.  Basically only the success and fails need a reducer statement.  How do I do this with the toolkit?  Do I have to put in a reducer that just returns the unchanged state for the load actions?

Answer (score 1):

With redux-toolkit you have a few options here...

#### 1. Existing thunks + RTK actions

If you only need to update one slice of your store with the loaded data, you can create “success” and “fail” actions in the `reducers` property on that slice. Then, change your thunk to dispatch those instead of the old success/fail actions.

```js
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    fetchDataSuccess(state, action) {
      // Do something with the response
    },
    fetchDataError(state, action) {
      // Do something with the error
    }
  }
}

const { fetchDataSuccess, fetchDataError } = slice.actions

export function fetchData() {
  return dispatch => api.getData()
    .then(response => dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(response.data)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(fetchDataError(error))
}

export default slice.reducer
```

#### 2. Existing thunks + `extraReducers`

If you don't want to refactor the existing thunk, or if the actions will be used across multiple slices, you can use the [`extraReducers`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers) property.

```js
// These can also be defined in a separate file and imported
const FETCH_SUCCESS = 'data/FETCH_SUCCESS'
const FETCH_FAIL = 'data/FETCH_FAIL'

export function fetchData() {
  return dispatch => api.getData()
    .then(response => dispatch({ type: FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: response.data }))
    .catch(error => dispatch({ type: FETCH_FAIL, payload: error }))
}

const slice = createSlice({
  // ... the usual properties
  extraReducers: {
    [FETCH_SUCCESS](state, action) {
      // Do something with the response
    },
    [FETCH_FAIL](state, action) {
      // Do something with the error
    }
  }
}
```

#### 3. `createAsyncThunk`

This approach is similar to the above, but the [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) utility handles a lot of it for you, like catching errors, dispatching the actions at the right time, etc.

```js
const fetchData = createAsyncThunk(
  'data/fetchData',
  () => api.getData().then(response => response.data)
)

const slice = createSlice({
  // ... the usual properties
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchData.fulfilled](state, action) {
      // Do something with the response
    },
    [fetchData.rejected](state, action) {
      // Do something with action.error
    }
  }
}

// Components still call this like a normal function: fetchData()
export { fetchData }

export default slice.reducer
```

Whichever way you end up going, if you're not using the "load" action (or `.pending` from `createAsyncThunk`), you don't need to add it to either `reducers` or `extraReducers`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply create `thunk-actions.ts` (or eg. saga-actions.ts) file to keep actions that trigger data loading.

```
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const fetchUserComments = createAction<{ id: string }>(
    'fetchUserComments',
);
```

and then "merge" them with slice's actions, just for convenience

```
export userActions = {...userSlice.actions, fetchUserComments };
```

all actions that have reducer's logic will be generated by slice